# Gettng memory leak error while adding new changeset in liquibase

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

i am adding new changeset in liquibase and i got error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin\java" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=51315:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.4\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper C:\Users\ankitaggarwal\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_classpath com.ab
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
   ___      _       _       _       _              __ _  
  | _ \    | |     | |     | |     | |   | ' \    \__, | 
_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| 
"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' 


2018-11-01 10:46:41.151  WARN [b,,,] 22752 --- [ost-startStop-2] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [pollingConfigurationSource] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This error occur only when i add new changeset but this work fine if remove that added changeset.

This problem come for every changeset.

Comment: Please show the value you have for liquibase.change-log in your application properties/yaml file.

Comment: @JonckvanderKogel Error occur in new line also.